# Probability of event B occurring after event A

Tags: probability

Why isn't it 1/5*1/4=1/20? Why doesn't the so-called rule of product apply? What formula, what rule should I have used instead? The explanation just lists all the pairs and, since there are 10 pairs in total and only one desired pair, says it's 1/10. But I want some formula. I thought multiplying probabilities of two consecutive events was the one

[image]

[image]

For screen-readers: "Two of the [five] candidates are randomly selected to compete head to head on a Daily Challenge. What is the probability that the candidates selected are Emmy and Srinivasa?"

Comment: Presumably there are 5 candidates.  There are $10$ possible pairs not $20$, and choosing  Emmy then Srinivasa, or  Srinivasa then Emmy,  results in the same pair being chosen

Comment: You can evaluate it as $\frac{1}{5}\cdot \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}\cdot \frac{1}{4}$, which is the prob of choosing Srini first, Emmy second OR Emmy first, Srini second.

Comment: @golden_ratio good, it's helpful. Thanks

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev ofc, no prob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule of product does apply, but you have to choose the events carefully to make sure you're measuring what you want to measure.  You're trying to measure the probability that Emmy and Srinivasa are chosen *in either order*.  It's not correct that your first event is choosing Emmy because it's possible that you'll first choose Srinivasa and then choose Emmy.  Similarly, it's not correct that your first event is choosing Srinivasa because it's possible that you'll first choose Emmy and then choose Srinivasa.

The first event is that *either* Emmy *or* Srinivasa is picked.  That event has probability $\frac 25$.  The second event is that the remaining member of that pair is picked.  The second event has probability $\frac 14$, so that product is $\frac {1}{10}$.